# Why django can serve media files but can not serve static files

Tags: python, django

I've set up Apache for my django project, and here's the code that I add in the Apache httpd.conf file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / E:/Django/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath E:Django/mysite/

<Directory E:/Django/mysite/mysite/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted`
</Files>
</Directory>
```

The server runs without problem, but the strange thing is, when I browse my website, I find that all the media files are successfully loaded, but all the static files can not be loaded (In the browser console ,it reports a 404 (NOT FOUND) error).

Here are the settings in the settings.py file about media files and static files:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL='/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media"),)
```

And in the urls.py, I didn't add anything like urlpatterns +=static(...,...)

Can anyone help me figure out why media files are okay but static files cannot be loaded?

Comment: here is how it's done during development / production: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/ . Personally, I'd try adding the url patterns: `urlpatterns = [<PATTERNS>] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: For Apache/mod_wsgi see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't handle static files in production. You need to link the static files with apache or if using Nginx

Mod_wsgi:

```
Alias /static/ /path/to/project/static/
<Directory /path/to/project/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

or nginx:

```
location /static/ {
        alias /opt/project/static/;
    }
```

At least this is the correct way to do it, let your server handle them, or in nginx's case your reverse proxy.